# How to read this expression?

Tags: c, flash, struct, typecast-operator

```
(long)&((FLASH_CONF_STRUCT*)0)->vlan
```

`FLASH_CONF_STRUCT` is a struct type, and `vlan` is a member of this struct.

How to spell this expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(FLASH_CONF_STRUCT*)` is a type cast. It's casting `0` to a pointer that points to a `FLASH_CONF_STRUCT`. Let's call this `ptr`.

`ptr->vlan` is equivalent to `(*ptr).vlan`. It accesses the `vlan` field of the structure pointed by `ptr`.

`&` gets the address of what follows, so the offset of `vlan` added to `ptr`.

`(long)` casts the address to a `long`.

Overall, this is meant to get the offset of `vlan` within the structure. But I suspect it invokes *Undefined Behaviour* (because it dereferences a NULL pointer, at the very least). And it does so needlessly.

Replace

```
long ofs = (long)&((FLASH_CONF_STRUCT*)0)->vlan;
```

with the far more readable

```
#include <stddef.h>

size_t ofs = offsetof(FLASH_CONF_STRUCT, vlan);
```

For example,

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
   int a;
   int b;
   int vlan;
} FLASH_CONF_STRUCT;

int main(void) {
   printf("%ld\n", (long)&((FLASH_CONF_STRUCT*)0)->vlan);
   printf("%zu\n", offsetof(FLASH_CONF_STRUCT, vlan));
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c99 a.c -o a && a
8
8
```